# Enable streak gmail tracking while using gmail api

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm using gmail api to send emails to a particular group of people, however it would be really great if i can track these emails using streak after sending them.

Any idea how to get streak tracking works with gmail api ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with integrating Streak API with Gmail API. Check these references that can help you:

- [Streak API tutorial](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/streak)
- [Streak API documentation](https://www.streak.com/api/)
- [Email View Tracking](https://www.streak.com/email-tracking-in-gmail)